# Setting sound configuration for Socket device

Tags: android, ios, socketscan

Using the following code to attempt setting the sound on/off for a Socket 8ci...not quite working for me.  Can you suggest a proper command?  As you can see in the code I set the Sound frequency based on a preference boolean.  Thanks!

```
DeviceInfo device = (DeviceInfo) _scanApiHelper.getDevicesList().lastElement();
short[] soundConfig = new short[3];
// default the sound to On
if(getBRSharedPreferenceBoolean(PreferencesActivity.PREF_SOCKET_SCANNER_BEEP, true)) {
    soundConfig[0] = ISktScanProperty.values.soundFrequency.kSktScanSoundFrequencyHigh;
} else {
    soundConfig[0] = ISktScanProperty.values.soundFrequency.kSktScanSoundFrequencyNone;
}
soundConfig[1] = 200;
soundConfig[2] = 100;

// set the scanner sound config
_scanApiHelper.postSetSoundConfigDevice(
        device,
        ISktScanProperty.values.soundActionType.kSktScanSoundActionTypeGoodScan,
        soundConfig,
        _onSetScanApiConfiguration);
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to come up with a solution. From your question it wasn't immediately clear *what* wasn't working, so I spent a day looking into an invalid parameter exception before I realized that was not the problem you were seeing. I also have all the sounds disabled on my scanners which makes it difficult to test the sound profiles :-)

Comment: No problem!  Thanks for the concise solution!  Works great...now I'll try it on iOS.

Comment: Capture SDK is great! Anyone using Socket Mobile devices should definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

#### Sound Config Device

The sound config allows you to set 4 different "actions": `kSktScanSoundActionTypeGoodScan`, `kSktScanSoundActionTypeGoodScanLocal`, `kSktScanSoundActionTypeBadScan`, `kSktScanSoundActionTypeBadScanLocal`. The difference between `GoodScan` and `BadScan` is self-explanatory, but the difference between `GoodScan` and `GoodScanLocal` isn't very clear.

`GoodScanLocal`, by default, is the sound emitted when a barcode is scanned

`GoodScan` is only emitted when the host (e.g. Android, iOS, Windows) sends the scanner a GoodScan or BadScan notification (via `kSktScanPropIdDataConfirmationDevice`)

> Note: If you are using `GoodScan`/`BadScan` to verify decoded data, you probably want to change the confirmation mode (see `kSktScanPropIdDataConfirmationMode` in the docs). Otherwise the scanner will beep/flash/vibrate twice per scan

The code snippet your snippet is based on uses the latter to demonstrate that the tone is both configurable and can be triggered by the host.

You select a tone, hit the confirm button and the scanner emits that tone. It's not clear at first glance, but if you change the tone using the dropdown in SingleEntry and hit confirm, the three tones are very distinct. However, if you change the tone using that same dropdown, the tone you hear when you scan a barcode should not change.

### The Solution

The best and simplest way to achieve what you are trying to achieve is to set the *Local Decode Action* with the beep disabled

#### Local Decode Action

```
// import static com.socketmobile.scanapi.ISktScanProperty.values.localDecodeAction.*;

DeviceInfo device = (DeviceInfo) _scanApiHelper.getDevicesList().lastElement();
int decodeAction = kSktScanLocalDecodeActionFlash | kSktScanLocalDecodeActionRumble;
if(getBRSharedPreferenceBoolean(PreferencesActivity.PREF_SOCKET_SCANNER_BEEP, true)) {
    decodeAction |= kSktScanLocalDecodeActionBeep;
}
_scanApiHelper.postSetDecodeAction(device, decodeAction)
```

For completeness sake, to achieve a similar result using the code you posted, you'd only need to change `kSktScanSoundActionTypeGoodScan` to `kSktScanSoundActionTypeGoodScanLocal`. Although I would not recommend it.